# Magento 2 How to add all country regions in database?

Tags: magento2, database, country-regions

I checked `directory_country_region` in the database there is no region of the United Kingdom, I need all region of United Kingdom.

Is Magento provide the sheet of all country regions or from where I can add them?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 1: You can use the direct SQL files to add regions into database. For this you can refer [this post](http://magento2-blog.com/magento-add-regions-to-country/).

Another way is You can use the Magento custom code to add regions into database. For this you can refer [this post](http://www.sycha.com/magento-add-custom-state-province-region-country).

Also I have found one extension "[Regions Manager](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/regions-manager.html)" that provide facility to add/update regions from backend.

**UPDATE**

> The solution which I did to add United Kingdom Regions is: I found a
>   CSV for united Kingdom states here: [Here is the CSV](https://www.designhaven.co.uk/2015/06/adding-county-regions-states-provinces-in-magento-to-include-dropdown-in-cart/)

Just import it in Database and its save my time and effort.